# Receiving "You passed an empty string" error when updating connected account identity information using Stripe Connect Custom API (PHP)

Tags: php, stripe-connect

I'm making a form to update/add identity information using the Stripe Connect Custom API. But I am receiving a **"You passed an empty string"** error from the API **for fields that I am not submitting**.

```
$legal_entity = array(
    'first_name'=>$first_name,
    'last_name'=>$last_name,
    'maiden_name'=>$maiden_name,
    'personal_id_number'=>$personal_id_number,
    'dob' => array(
        'day' => $dob_day,
        'month' => $dob_month,
        'year' => $dob_year
    ),
    'personal_address' => array(
        'line1' => $address_line1,
        'line2' => $address_line2,
        'city' => $address_city,
        'state' => $address_state,
        'country' => $address_country,
        'postal_code' => $address_postal_code
    ),

);

$account = \Stripe\Account::retrieve($stripe_account_id);
$account->legal_entity = $legal_entity;
$account->save();
```

> You passed an empty string for 'legal_entity[type]'. We assume empty values are an attempt to unset a parameter; however 'legal_entity[type]' cannot be unset. You should remove 'legal_entity[type]' from your request or supply a non-empty value.

As you can see; I don't define the [type] member at all.  If I add it; I then get the following error instead:

> You passed an empty string for 'legal_entity[address]'. We assume empty values are an attempt to unset a parameter; however 'legal_entity[address]' cannot be unset. You should remove 'legal_entity[address]' from your request or supply a non-empty value.

EDIT: If I try retrieving the [legal_entity] and simply updating it and resaving it; like this:

```
$account = \Stripe\Account::retrieve($stripe_account_id);
$legal_entity = $account->legal_entity;


$legal_entity['first_name'] = $first_name;

$legal_entity['last_name'] = $last_name;

$legal_entity['maiden_name'] = $maiden_name;

$legal_entity['personal_id_number'] = $personal_id_number;

$legal_entity['dob'] = array(
    'day' => $dob_day,
    'month' => $dob_month,
    'year' => $dob_year
);

$legal_entity['personal_address'] = array(
    'line1' => $address_line1,
    'line2' => $address_line2,
    'city' => $address_city,
    'state' => $address_state,
    'country' => $address_country,
    'postal_code' => $address_postal_code
);


$account->legal_entity = $legal_entity;
$account->save();
```

I get the following error:

> Once a full set of basic legal entity information has been provided (type, business_name, first_name, last_name, and address), you cannot unset any of it, only update it.

How do I update the account holder or additional owners?

Comment: Looks like `type` is required to be a non-empty value?

Comment: [here it states](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/required-verification-information) that for Canada (*judged from your profile*) that `legal_entity.type` is a required field.

Comment: I defined [type] when I created the account.  As I said in my question; if I do [re]define it in my update; the API then complains about the next object that I didn't [re]define (e.g. [address]).  
If I just want to update one or a few fields; should I have to rebuild the entire legal_entity object (which includes up to 4 additional owners) and resubmit everything?

Comment: Ok, are you unable to redefine all values? [Does this link help?](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification-api)

Comment: I suppose I could redefine all values (and I will if I have to).  But there are a lot of values ([legal_entity] also contains information for up to 4 additional owners).  If I just want to update one or a few fields; that seems like a lot to have to do.

Comment: I think you only need to redefine the four *required* values.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that my suggestion will work but it looks like you completely override `legal_entity` with new data. Try to merge existing data with new one. Something like:

```
$legal_entity = array(
    'first_name'=>$first_name,
    'last_name'=>$last_name,
    'maiden_name'=>$maiden_name,
    'personal_id_number'=>$personal_id_number,
    'dob' => array(
        'day' => $dob_day,
        'month' => $dob_month,
        'year' => $dob_year
    ),
    'personal_address' => array(
        'line1' => $address_line1,
        'line2' => $address_line2,
        'city' => $address_city,
        'state' => $address_state,
        'country' => $address_country,
        'postal_code' => $address_postal_code
    ),

);

$account = \Stripe\Account::retrieve($stripe_account_id);
$account->legal_entity = array_merge($account->legal_entity, $legal_entity);
$account->save();
```

Comment: I tried something similar; that's how I got my third error.  It appears that there's information in legal_entity that one can't resubmit.

Comment: @HardlyNoticeable also i can advice you to use `array_merge_recursive` instead of `array_merge`

Answer (score 0):

Omit `$account->legal_entity = $legal_entity;` in your updated example.

This, for example, works just fine!

```
// see https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#update_account for all options
$account = \Stripe\Account::create(array(
  "type" => "custom",
  "country" => "US",
  "email" => "test@example.com"
));

// retrieve and update the account
$account = \Stripe\Account::retrieve($account->id);

$legal_entity = $account->legal_entity;

$legal_entity['type'] = "individual";
$legal_entity['first_name'] = "Jane";
$legal_entity['last_name'] = "Allen";
$legal_entity['personal_id_number'] = "000000000";

$legal_entity['dob'] = array(
    'day' => 1,
    'month' => 1,
    'year' => 1901
);

$legal_entity['address'] = array(
    'line1' => "1 Main St",
    'line2' => "Suite 111",
    'city' => "San Francisco",
    'state' => "CA",
    'country' => "US",
    'postal_code' => "94103"
);

$account->tos_acceptance = array(
    'date' => time(), 
    "ip" => "10.10.0.10"
);

echo $account->save();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how $legal_entity information is saved when $account is saved.  does $legal_entity = $account->legal_entity; create a reference?